# How to decode image from stream, into existing image

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection

I have an application which plays audio with NAudio. A known limitation with NAudio is that every time the Garbage Collector runs, every thread is paused until it is done.

The application runs fine, all GC is done within acceptable time and there is no stuttering.

But we also have an separate application that sends a thumbnail to the main application (with the audio player) over TCP every second. The Thumbnail is about 1300 bytes when encoded as JPEG.

This is the code we are currently using to decode the image:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
BitmapDecoder bdec = BitmapDecoder.Create(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
BitmapSource source = bdec.Frames[0];
imgPreview.Source = source;
```

And to encode:

```
JpegBitmapEncoder jpgEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
jpgEncoder.QualityLevel = quality;
jpgEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTarget));

byte[] imageArray;
using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    jpgEncoder.Save(outputStream);
    imageArray = outputStream.ToArray();
}
```

Where RenderTarget is a RenderTargetBitmap that have the image content.

Right now we are creating and throwing away a MemoryStream, a BitmapDecoder, and a BitmapSource every second. I have commented out lines from the code and it looks like the MemoryStream and the BitmapDecoder constructor does not create any stutter, but once it's accessed through Frames[0], it starts to stutter.

We have also tried this approach instead of the BitmapDecoder, but with same results:

```
img.BeginInit();
img.StreamSource = ms;
img.EndInit();
```

Surely there is a better way to continuously update an image?

The best way would be to just send over the raw image data, and create a WriteableBitmap, which are just rewritten every second. But the raw image is 170 kb, over 100 times more than the encoded image, and we really don't want to do that. Is it possible to decode a JPEG stream into an existing byte array, or existing image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I have found the solution to my problem.

Instead of using the WPF BitmapDecoder to decode the images, I'm using the Windows Forms Bitmap. It is disposable, and much nicer to the Garbage Collector.

So the solution is as follows:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
var formsBitmap = new Bitmap(stream);

var width = formsBitmap.Width;
var height = formsBitmap.Height;
if (bitmap == null || height != bitmap.PixelHeight || width != bitmap.PixelWidth)
{
    bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32, null);
    imgPreview.Source = bitmap;
}

BitmapData data = formsBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, formsBitmap.Width, formsBitmap.Height),
                                        ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

try
{
    bitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), data.Scan0, data.Stride * data.Height, data.Stride);
}
finally
{
    formsBitmap.UnlockBits(data);
}

formsBitmap.Dispose();
```

Instead of decoding every JPEG frame I receive, I create a new Bitmap (from WinForms) from the data. Then I simply copy the pixels to only WriteableBitmap I use.

Hopefully this can be of help to others as well.

Comment: I think it's even better to `LockBits` directly into the `bitmap.BackBuffer` using the `UserInputBuffer` mode: http://pastebin.com/Qv4XjYay

Answer (score 1):

Profiling the code confirms that **bdec.Frames[0];** takes a relatively large chunk of CPU time. Looking at the code in ILSpy the '**Frames**' getter has an empty implementation (virtual method not overridden by the JpgBitmapDecodersub-class), so I assume there is some kind of call made to the underlying Windows API going on there(?)

The bottom line is that decoding JPG is going to be slower than say PNG or GIF; I would try PNG encoding as it should still give a good compression ratio but with better performance.

Comment: Well, I have tried the same thing, but instead of decoding the image, I just created a new, empty WriteableBitmap with size 500x500. The same thing happens. Besides, this runs on a separate thread than my Audio Player, and the only thing that pauses all threads are the GC. So the problem is not the time taken by the method, but the garbage collection that happens afterwards.

Comment: Interesting. I would guess that the image decode is being done outside of managed code and that this is the cause of the delay, possibly (as you suggest) by the triggering of GC pass. It might be worth looking at the GC stats in PerfMon to confirm if a GC pass is occuring. I'd also give the PNG format a try as JPG codec has some legacy code in it which may be the cause of the odd behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, just re-read, so you factored out the encoding as being the problem by using a raw bitmap?

Comment: Yes, the decoding is not a problem. By creating a WriteableBitmap, and commenting out the rest of the code, even imgPreview = source, I experienced the same symptoms.

Comment: Can you confirm that the audio code is running on a background thread (not the GUI thread).

Comment: Yes. And I can reproduce the problem by creating the empty, 500x500 WriteableBitmap on another thread, so it's not a problem with the GUI thread either.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30789/discussion-between-locster-and-akselk)

Comment: @locster Obiously, the `BitmapDecoder.Frames` getter is not empty.